# in React $(…).highcharts method "Uncaught TypeError: is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

The code must iterate over 'data' and create three charts in the DOM.
the actual code is long and not easily reproducible. It's a mock code. I know It's not advisable to append to DOM via jQuery append method.

and mock code is like this:

```
 export class Combination extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
          $.ajax(url:'something'
          ...
          success(data): {
              data.map(function(dataset){

              $('<div id="chart">')
              .append('#combination')
              .highchart({
                 chart: {
                  ...
                 }
              })
            }
          }
          )
    }
 }
```

The error is  "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).appendTo(...).highcharts is not a function"

when i change the code 
from:

```
  .highchart({
    ...
```

to:

```
  Highchart.chart('chart',{
  })
```

but what it creates is like this:

```
 <div id='chart' data-highcharts-chart="2"></div>
 <div id='chart'></div>
 <div id='chart'></div>
```

it must creates charts like this:

```
 <div id='chart' data-highcharts-chart="0"></div>
 <div id='chart' data-highcharts-chart="1"></div>
 <div id='chart' data-highcharts-chart="2"></div>
```

it is obvious it is not iterating properly.

Comment: You don't need JQuery at all. Try an npm module like axios for your requests. Ditch jQuery all together.

Comment: That's a very nice point but 50k extra library is not that big of a deal for me.

Comment: Yeah, but jQuery manipulates the DOM in ways that is in complete opposition to how React works under the hood.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct. but that is not exactly the problem here. the problem is that .highcharts method is not recognized as a function. But If you know how to properly change this code to react that'll be very good too.

Comment: What i want to do is iterate over data and create three charts.

Comment: Ill try to get a codepen example working on break at work if this question isn't answered by then

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen jquery inside a react component. Regardless, you need unique IDs for your charts.

Comment: In the previous react documentation all the XMLHttpRequest were ajax request. About the unique IDs, If i was iterating over JSX nodes you were right but i am appending dom elements via jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Daniel Zuzevich that jQuery doesn't gel well with React. So fundamentally, this approach is flawed.

Having said that, I would guess that it is because you're using a static `id`. Why don't you try and create a unique `id` for each mapped item.

```
data.map(function(dataset, key){

          $(`<div id="chart${key}">`)
          .append('#combination')

          Highchart.chart(`chart${key}`, {
             chart: {
              ...
             }
          })
```

Comment: Yes. that was correct. Sorry for out of the ordinary question. I will change to proper react component and post it here. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Of course. We all came from the jQuery world and have trouble adjusting to the 'React way' of thinking. Once you get there, it's so easy! Good luck!